# cambiar fondo con Js segun la hora del dia

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me piden hacer el cambio de fondo dependiendo de la hora del día utilizando JS Tengo lo siguiente pero no se como llamar los fondos de CSS
funciona solo con el JS del html pero quieren que se arrastre el fondo desde CSS
HTML

```
<script>
function myBackground(){
fecha = new Date();
hora = fecha.getHours();
if(hora>=1 && hora<=10){//imagen desde la 1am hasta las 10am
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage="url('img/Fondo1.jpg')";
}
if(hora>=11 && hora<=18){//imagen desde las 11am hasta las 6pm  
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage="url('img/Fondo1.jpg')";
}
if(hora>=19 && hora<=24){//imagen desde las 7pm hasta las 12pm
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage="url('img/Fondo3.jpg')";
}
}
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML +  myBackground();
</script>
```

CSS

```
body.home {
    background-image: url( 'img/fondo 1.png.png' ) !important;
}

body.home.day {
    background-image: url( 'img/fondo 1.png' ) !important;
}

body.home.sunrise {
    background-image: url( 'img/fondo 1.png' ) !important;
}

body.home.sunset {
    background-image: url( 'img/fondo 2.png' ) !important;
}

body.home.night {
     background-image: url( 'img/fondo 3.png' ) !important;
}
```

Comment: Puedes usar `element.classList` para agregar clases, por ejemplo: `document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add('day')` o `document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove('day')` si quiere quitarla. Aquí puedes encontrar más información https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList;

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.